# MPMoviePlayerController - numberofBytesTransferred decreased on time

Tags: ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

My Task - To get "Number of Bytes Transferred for every 100 milliseconds on playing a video , then plot a graph with these values with respect to time played".

My approach -

Get NSArray of MPMovieAccessLogEvent from MPMoviePlayerController every 100ms, catch the last one in the array, call MPMovieAccessLogEvent.numberOfBytesTransferred. Thats it. DONE.

Expected - Upon time, Number of bytes transferred should increase in value.

**Problem - "When I plot a graph with these values" - Surprisingly I see, the Bytes Transferred is dipping at some areas ( Guess - May be for every increase in count of MPMovieAccessLogEvents provided by MPMoviePlayerController).**

Please help me out.

Thanks much,
Sha.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im using HLS which means it does have different pieces of files to download, and hence more event logs.

The answer is simple --> Aggregate the bytes values of all the MPMovieAccessLogEvent's present.